# Query parameters to be passed for unpaged results in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

What query parameters should be passed for unpaged results in Spring, so that I can retrieve results as unpaged (i.e. all rows in the table). Existing call implementation is as follows, but I would like the user interface client to pass pagination parameters if needed or provide unpaged results

```
@GetMapping
public PageableResponse fetchCountries(Pageable pageable) {
    return countryService.findAll(pageable);
}
```

Comment: Not sure this will work, but try a request where the client does not send `page` and `size` query parameters, so that `pageable.isPaged()` returns false.

Comment: @AndrewS this will not work. If parameters are absent then Spring provides the default: page=0 size=20 SORTED.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an additional endpoint for all countries:

```java
@GetMapping("all-countries")
public List<Country> fetchAllCountries() {
    return countryService.findAll();
}
```

Or introduce an optional query parameter:

```java
@GetMapping
public List<Country> fetchCountries(RequestParam(required=false) boolean all,
                                    Pageable pageable) {
    if (all) {
        return countryService.findAll();
    } else {
        return countryService.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, but wanted to provide a single endpoint to manage both else  there will be more endpoints to manage

Comment: Sure. But you must provide something to distinguish both cases. If not the additional endpoint then maybe an optional query parameter like `all=true`?